# Tetraeder volume geometry problem

Tags: geometry

Here is the problem.

> The volume of tetraeder $ABCD$ is $1$. On side lines $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$ are
>   taken points $K$, $L$, $M$, and $N$ respectively, so that $AK = AB/3$, $BL =
> > BC/4$, $CM = CD/5$, $DN = DA/6$. We should find the volume of $KLMN$ tetraeder.

I encounter difficulties while solving this.

Here is what I've found so far.
[image]

I tried to find the side length of $ABCD$, while denoting it with a, I got
$V= 1/3 * h * S$. 
$a^3 = 12/sqrt{2}$. $S=\frac{x^2 * \sqrt{3}}{4}$. The same way denoting the side length of $KLMN$ with $x$ I got $x^3 =  \frac {a^3 * 181 * \sqrt{181} }{8000}$ and $h = \frac{x*\sqrt{6}}{3}$. But while putting this values in $V$'s formula I got a wrong answer. 
Couldn't find out alternative way.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you know about the cross product of vectors?

Comment: No, I don't know, can you send a link or show another way of solution @MichaelHoppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to draw the edge $MN$!

You may assume $A=(0,0,0)$, $C=(1,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$, $D=(0,0,1)$. This tetrahedron has volume ${1\over6}$ instead of $1$, but never mind. Now find the coordinates of $K$, $M$, $L$, $N$ in this setup. Use $K$ as "origin" of the small tetrahedron, and compute the coordinates of the three vectors $m:=\vec{KM}$, $l:=\vec{KL}$, $n:=\vec{KN}$. The volume of the small tetrahedron is then given by ${1\over6}\bigl|[m,l,n]\bigr|$, whereby $[\ ,\ ,\ ]$ denotes the triple vector product. Draw conclusions.

Comment: aren't KM, KL and KN vectors equal? @ChristianBlatter

Comment: All four points $K$, $M$, $L$, $N$ have certain coordinates in "my" system. You obtain the coordinates of the vector $m:=\vec{KM}$ by subtracting the coordinates of $K$ from the coordinates of $M$, etcetera.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And one more question, please. Why the volume gets 1/6 multiplied the triple product of vectors @Christian Blatter

Comment: Look at the situation for $b:=\vec{AB}$, $c:=\vec{AC}$, $d:=\vec{AD}$. The full triple vector product there gives the volume of the unit cube.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter How do you prove that the answer is the same for any tetrahedron?

Comment: @Maxim: This is implicitly assumed in the posing of the question. Otherwise additional data would be required. It has to do with the fact that affine maps multiply *all* volumes by the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = (0, 0, 0)$. The volume of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ is proportional to the determinant of the matrix with rows $B, C, D$. Since $K = 2/3 A + 1/3 B$ and similarly for other points, $L - K, M - K, N - K$ are given by multiplying $B, C, D$ by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac 5 {12} & \frac 1 4 & 0 \\
 -\frac 1 3 & \frac 4 5 & \frac 1 5 \\
 -\frac 1 3 & 0 & \frac 5 6
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The answer is the determinant of this matrix.